# TableView NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Update: It seems like I managed to identify the cell, so the original problem is solved. But now, with the same code snipped, I get the following error:

```
2012-10-31 15:21:41.857 Laktase[22658:11603] -[NSManagedObject isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74a5a30
2012-10-31 15:21:41.858 Laktase[22658:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74a5a30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1f9f012 0x13dce7e 0x202a4bd 0x1f8ebbc 0x1f8e94e 0x1714af 0x171674 0x4430 0xd2f4b 0xd301f 0xbb80b 0xcc19b 0x6892d 0x13f06b0 0x259bfc0 0x259033c 0x259beaf 0x1078cd 0x501a6 0x4ecbf 0x4ebd9 0x4de34 0x4dc6e 0x4ea29 0x51922 0xfbfec 0x48bc4 0x48dbf 0x48f55 0x51f67 0x15fcc 0x16fab 0x28315 0x2924b 0x1acf8 0x1efadf9 0x1efaad0 0x1f14bf5 0x1f14962 0x1f45bb6 0x1f44f44 0x1f44e1b 0x167da 0x1865c 0x268d 0x25b5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

// End of Update

I'm trying to query a database and then list the results in a table for the first time.

When I change the numberOfRowsInSection from 0 to [matchingData count], the app crashes with a NSInternalInconsistencyException error. matchingData is an array with the results from core data. I just can't figure out why [matchingData count] doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tablette" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dosis >= 0"]; // @"ANY Tablette.dosis like '1'"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    return [matchingData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...


NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tablette" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dosis >= 1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

cell.textLabel.text = [matchingData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
2012-10-31 12:10:38.995 Laktase[21797:11603] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:4460
2012-10-31 12:10:38.996 Laktase[21797:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1f9f012 0x13dce7e 0x1f9ee78 0xb66f35 0xc9d14 0x4078 0xd2f4b 0xd301f 0xbb80b 0xcc19b 0x6892d 0x13f06b0 0x259bfc0 0x259033c 0x259beaf 0x1078cd 0x501a6 0x4ecbf 0x4ebd9 0x4de34 0x4dc6e 0x4ea29 0x51922 0xfbfec 0x48bc4 0x48dbf 0x48f55 0x51f67 0x15fcc 0x16fab 0x28315 0x2924b 0x1acf8 0x1efadf9 0x1efaad0 0x1f14bf5 0x1f14962 0x1f45bb6 0x1f44f44 0x1f44e1b 0x167da 0x1865c 0x249d 0x23c5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show us the actual exception output please?

Comment: Does the number of `Tablette` objects ever change? If so, you need to make sure that you call `[UITableView reloadData]` or you will cause as inconsistency between the data source and what is displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, good to know, but in this case it does not change.

Comment: Well it seems it is because of the missing reusable identifier in the nib if I am correct.

Comment: Can you show your cellForRowAtIndexPath function?

Comment: Ok I've added it. Thanks so far! What does that reusable identifier mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign the correct Cell identifier to your prototype cell in the Nib/Storyboard.

The error is clear: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for

Comment: Not sure (I must know the exact data structure of your objects), but I think that this line `cell.textLabel.text = [matchingData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` should look like: `cell.textLabel.text = [[matchingData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] aMethodReturningText]` or something similar. You must point to a NSString, now you are pointing to an NSManagedObject instance

Comment: Ok, I changed it to: cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [matchingData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; Not the app starts, the table appears, but I can only see lines similar to this: "<NSManagedObject: 0x817c520> (ent...". Whats this?

Comment: Now you are printing the description of your object!!!! :-) I try to explain: inside the array matchingData you have some NSManagedObject instances. You are trying to print something on screen. What are you trying to print? A name? A text? Ok, this name/text is stored in one of the NSManagedObject instance properties. So, to print it, you must write something like `cell.textLabel.text = [[matchingData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] propertyName]` where propertyName is the name of the property containing the text you want to show! Paste your object .h properties list :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! :-) I tried this line of code: cell.textLabel.text = [[matchingData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"dosis"]; Now the database is in the table, but 3 times :-D How did that happen? When I count it with [matchingData count] it says 3 matches, which is right, but the table shows 9... :-)

Comment: Mmmhhh...Looking better at your code, I suggest you to refactor it. You are making a NSFetchRequest each time the tableview calls it's datasource (one time for each line in the database), and another request to have the count. I suggest you to do only one fetch request in some init method and put all your data inside an array or, better, use a NSFetchedResultsController. The issue you are describing is probably because you are doing different requests to have the count and the objects (the predicate is different).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Try the following:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Very important to test if cell is null, always happens to the first cell configured in section

```
if (cell == nil)
{ //alloc the cell explicitily

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
    .....
}

// Configure the cell.
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Have a nice day